# Web crawler only returns partial content

Tags: php, web-crawler, steam

Me and a friend of mine are trying to index all of the Steam games and their IDs into a database table.

So far, we have succeeded in indexing the first 75 games, starting with the most recent release. The problem is, though, that we do not know why it only returns the first 75, as opposed to all of them. The crawler is written in PHP.

Here are the sources: http://pastebin.com/cQfU38PQ titled index.php and http://pastebin.com/RpT20R6j titled class.php.

Every time we run the script, it takes about 10-20 seconds to run, and then it gives a blank page, as expected. The database, however, will only contain 75 entries. Nowhere in the script have we defined for how long it should run, or how many entries it should index.
I also made sure that the php script is given enough time to execute as per the settings in php.ini.

Can you help us find why it stops after indexing 75 entries?

Comment: A few notes for you; firstly, do Steam offer an API or RSS feed for this? That would be easier to parse, and you'd be less likely to get blocked. Secondly, you aren't doing any delays between requests, so you might get blocked for excessively fast crawling (if they permit it at all). Thirdly, you're not escaping your input data, so Steam could run SQL of their own choosing specifically for you (i.e. a SQL injection vulnerability)! And lastly, you should run this on a cron, rather than in a web page.

Answer (score 2):

In your code line 11

```
$c = 3;
```

You are only getting 3 pages with 25 results each for a total of 75

You need to set this to 282 as that is the current number of total pages.

```
$c = 282;
```

Comment: Oh wow, we implemented that line for debugging purposes. Can't believe we missed that. Thanks a bunch!